# Doctrine $query->expr()->lt with setParameter

Tags: doctrine-orm, query-builder

Is it possible to use "setParameter" with "$query->expr()->lt"?  The nature of my query is comparing two datetime type columns.

This works

```
$query
    ->orWhere(
        $query->expr()
            ->lt('p.dateExportedToTranslation', 'p.dateUpdated')
    );
```

What tweak is needed for this to work

```
$query
    ->orWhere(
        $query->expr()
            ->lt('p.dateExportedToTranslation', ':dateUpdated')
    )
    ->setParameter('dateUpdated', 'p.dateUpdated');
```

This is the whole query

```
$query = $this->entityManager
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->from('AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\PrayersForToday', 'p')
    ->select(
        'p.reference, p.languageIso, p.title, p.prayer,
         p.rssSentence, p.keywords, p.scriptureReferences,
         p.availableResourceWebsites, p.contributedByMembershipReference'
    )
    ->orderBy('p.reference', 'ASC')
    ->setMaxResults('25');

$query
    ->orWhere(
        $query->expr()
            ->eq('p.dateExportedToTranslation', ':date')
    )
    ->setParameter('date', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');

$query
    ->orWhere(
        $query->expr()
            ->lt('p.dateExportedToTranslation', ':dateUpdated')
    )
    ->setParameter('dateUpdated', 'p.dateUpdated');
```

Comment: Let us know what is not working.

Comment: What is not working is using 'setParameter' to bind another table column for the purpose of date comparison (in my example using 'lt') Within my initial post under the heading "What tweak is needed for this to work" is what I have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p.updated` is a column and not a string that you are sending through the parameter. If you are comparing two columns (same or different tables) you need to the first one (titled 'This works'). Only if you sending a date value you need to use this:

```
$query
    ->orWhere(
        $query->expr()
            ->eq('p.dateExportedToTranslation', ':date')
    )
    ->setParameter('date', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```